# ReactJS why onClick is going to trigger two methods instead of one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have two methods addItem and removeItem.
I have also two buttons for these methods via onClick.
When I click on addItem button then both methods are triggered, please why?

```
<button id="a" type="button" onClick={addItem} className="button button-size-small">Add to cart</button>

{items.map((item, index) => {

    <button id="b" type="button" onClick={removeItem(item)}>Delete</button>

})}


const addItem = _ => {
        const item = { id: (new Date).getTime(), userId, choosedFlavor, amount };
        setItems([...items, item]);
    }

const removeItem = item => {
       console.log('remove', item);
    }
```

Comment: Because you're calling the `removeItem` function on every render instead of passing it to `onClick`. Try `() => removeItem(item)`.

Comment: onClick={removeItem(item)}. this is the problem. you are calling the removeItem(). when you use like this you are actually calling the function.

Comment: Many thanks guys :) It works now! So am I clear? It is rendered every time which means, when click on add button then the react is going to render the page and every placeholder {} is replaced by real value? That means it is rendered according number of cycles. BUT when we use arrow func then it is real callback func that is supposed to be called only when user click. Is it like that?